# How do I make the Script execution box in Atom bigger?

Tags: python, atom-editor

In Atom, I am currently coding a simple beginner program to get me antiquated with the general lingo of Python. I really love atom and how advanced it is, but I have a small problem. When I execute the code I have written in Atom using the script package, I find the output text is very small and not easily readable. Is there any way to change this?

(As you can see from this screenshot, it is pretty hard to read.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/pDl3u.png

Comment: I have tried dragging the top border of the output box up but It does not seem to budge, also making the text bigger does only make it bigger in the work space.

Comment: Upon messing around with it further I can just see that it just gets bigger based of how many lines of code are printed. Its fine if it is like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you get the "Error compiling Less stylesheet", just remove blank space before script-view... The correct version should be

```
.script-view .line {
        font-size: 20px;
   }
```

Answer (score 3):

Unluckily there is not font setting for the package and what you need to do is go into your editor stylesheet and add this in:

```
. script-view .line {
        font-size: 20px;
   }
```

Comment: I have added this to my styles.less but it is giving me this error. (Error compiling Less stylesheet: C:\Users\ben\.atom\styles.less and then Line number: 33 Unrecognised input)

Comment: What error? And try add it into other style files you have see if that does anything

Comment: Where would I find the other style-sheets?

Comment: If you are on mac it will be in the atom menu drop down

Comment: Does not matter anymore, I have scraped using Script. I am now using terminal-plus as it brings cmd straight into atom without any problems.